# __libc_csu_fini and __libc_csu_init undefined while following instructions for build-webos

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, glibc, webos, openembedded

I'm trying to build OpenWebOS and just following the plan laid out in the [build-webos](https://github.com/openwebos/build-webos) GitHub README.  I'm using a fresh 32-bit Ubuntu 12.10 installation.  Things have been a bit bumpy.

However, with a tweak here and there I managed to get up to step 350 out of 2500 or (or whatever) before it errors out.  The problem is the dependency of building glibc, and it's complaining about

```
(...)/sysdeps/i386/start.S:107: undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
(...)/sysdeps/i386/start.S:108: undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
```

Searching the web reveals various cases of people having this happen to them when not building glibc itself:

[ld complains: in function "_start", undefined reference to "__libc_csu_fini" & "__libc_csu_init"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280631/ld-complains-in-function-start-undefined-reference-to-libc-csu-fini)

[Linking a C program directly with ld fails with undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656317/cant-link-a-c-program)

But this is during the build of a custom *Embedded LIBC: eglibc*.  So it's a little different, and the closest case I can find is this [2009 thread on an OpenEmbedded list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.openembedded/26911).  I'm not sure how to put their patch into action in the confusing "bakefile"-laden universe of the WebOS build structure, which is dizzyingly weird.

The monster of a command line which is failing I will "simplify" down a little to the following:

> gcc  -m32   -march=i586 --sysroot=/home/webos/build-webos/BUILD-qemux86/sysroots/qemux86-tcbootstrap -nostdlib -nostartfiles -o iconv/iconvconfig  -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux.so.2   -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both csu/crt1.o csu/crti.o `gcc  -m32   -march=i586 --sysroot=/home/hostilefork/Projects/webos/build-webos/BUILD-qemux86/sysroots/qemux86-tcbootstrap  --print-file-name=crtbegin.o` iconv/iconvconfig.o iconv/strtab.o iconv/xmalloc.o iconv/hash-string.o  -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/webos/build-webos/BUILD-qemux86/work/i586-webos-linux/eglibc-2.16-r15+svnr20393/build-i586-webos-linux:math:elf:dlfcn:nss:nis:rt:resolv:crypt:nptl libc.so.6 libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgcc  `gcc  -m32   -march=i586 --sysroot=/home/webos/build-webos/BUILD-qemux86/sysroots/qemux86-tcbootstrap  --print-file-name=crtend.o` csu/crtn.o

I've got a **libc.a** and a **libc_nonshared.a** file in the directory.  There's no mention of `__libc_csu_init` or `__libc_csu_fini` in the nonshared version, but they're in the ordinary libc.a.  This seems backward from what people seem to act as if should be true, although... when I look in the `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` for what came with Ubuntu, both the shared and nonshared versions mention it.  Hmmm.

If anyone reads this and goes "hey, bet I know what's going on!" that would be nifty.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately WebOS build-desktop support only Ubuntu lts 12.04.

Install Ubuntu 12.04 and follow instructions at https://github.com/openwebos/build-webos

Comment: Hey Maxim.  Thanks for the advice...I will try this when I get a minute to go back and look at doing the Rebol WebOS port and let you know how it goes.

Comment: No Problem :-) Write me if you will stuck with something. For now webos are for a bit unstable, because a lot of work made and sometime it is not enough time to retest all

Comment: Vetting old posts where I didn't check an answer.  I'm afraid that priority-wise the WebOS building dropped off, because the friend asking me to look into it for him had quickly moved on to other fleeting interests.  :-)  But thank you for your answer; I'll assume it is correct!