# GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain Installation Issue

Tags: c, arm, embedded, gnu-toolchain

I am trying to install a GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain in order to integrate it with Sublime Text 3 in an Ubuntu machine.

I followed this steps, but I got an error:

1.Download the packet from "https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+downloadGo", then unzip the packet in Home directory:

```
cd ~/
tar -xvjf ~/Downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3-20160926-linux.tar.bz2
```

2.Test if the file exist, and permissions are ok.

```
ll ~/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin
-rwxrwxrwx 2 root root  776368 set 26 19:36 arm-none-eabi-gcc*

--- I obmited the others files... ---
```

3.Test if it works:

```
sudo ~/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
```

But I got this error:

```
bash: /home/fabio/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_4-2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this? My user is "fabio", but the owner of the file is root.

Comment: Not that this is your problem but you probably *shouldn't* have to run this compiler as `root` (i.e., with `sudo`).

Comment: On an Ubuntu machine, just install the gcc-arm-none-eabi package in the normal manner, and if you really need the most up-to-date version, use the PPA the launchpad site provides. This is probably more of an [ubuntu.se] thing.

Comment: What is the normal manner?

Comment: If I don't use "sudo" I get the same error.

Comment: @FabioDev : As he said using sudo is not your problem, it is just a bad idea and unnecessary.  If it was intended to be a solution, it would have been posted and an answer not a comment.

Comment: Any reason you don't use the ppa and install via packet manager? That's not a question about programming according to site-rules.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

["No such file or directory" error when executing a binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716702/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-executing-a-binary)

I was missing the /lib/ld-linux.so.2 file, which is needed to run 32-bit apps.