# Binary file linked with libc not exist

Tags: assembly, linker, gnu-assembler

i cannot start binary file compiled via GAS assembler...
I want to link my program with libc. It is not necessary, I just want to link with libc...

Makefile:

```
LFLAGS= -m elf_x86_64
BUILD_DIR= build
CRT_PATH= /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

all: create_build_directory hello_world

create_build_directory:
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

hello_world: hello_world.o
    ld $(LFLAGS) -o ${BUILD_DIR}/hello_world ${CRT_PATH}/crt1.o ${CRT_PATH}/crti.o \
        -lc ${BUILD_DIR}/hello_world.o ${CRT_PATH}/crtn.o

hello_world.o: hello_world.s
    as --64 hello_world.s -o ${BUILD_DIR}/hello_world.o
    @echo "Create object file"

clean:
    @rm -f ${BUILD_DIR}/hello_world.o ${BUILD_DIR}/hello_world
    @echo "Remove binary and object files"

.INTERMEDIATE: hello_world.o
```

hello_world.s:

```
.section .rodata
info: .asciz "my first program"

.text
    .global main
    main:
    # write(1, message, 17)
    movl     $1, %eax
    movq     $1, %rdi                # file handle 1 is stdout
    mov     $message, %rsi          # address of string to output
    mov     $17, %rdx               # number of bytes
    syscall                         # invoke operating system to do the write

    # exit(0)
    movl     $60, %eax              # system call 60 is exit
    xor     %rdi, %rdi              # we want return code 0
    syscall                         # invoke operating system to exit

data:
    message: .string "Hello world!!!\r\n"
```

Then i try to build and run executable file:

```
make && ./build/hello_world
bash: ./build/hello_world: No such file or directory
```

What is the reason? The compiled executable file actually exists on disk

Edit1:
ldd output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffceb81000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7e234db000)
/lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7e2387a000)
```

Edit2:
file ./build/hello_world:

```
./build/hello_world: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped
```

Comment: What does `ldd ./build/hello_world` print? Please edit the output into your question.

Comment: Also, is there a requirement that you use `as` and `ld` manually? Can you just let GCC call those things for you?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica i want with as and ld... for education

Comment: Duplicate of ["No such file or directory" error when executing a binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2716702) or similar.  (@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: can you add a tag like [linux] or [assembly] so I can dup-hammer when I find a duplicate that explains ld args.)

Comment: What does `file ./build/hello_world` say that the path to the interpreter is? And does that exist?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica edit2

Comment: Resolve, thanks all:
LFLAGS= -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2